# App working on Android 13 in release and debug mode but crashes on Android 12 and earlier release mode after updating react native version

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-api-levels, bump2version

I'm currently upgrading react native version in my app from 0.64.3 to 0.69.2, I'm also moving to new architecture, i made all the necessary changes for updating, made changes in manifest and so on to bump to api level 31 from 30, and updated some libraries.
At that point app is working fine in Android 11 and 12 debug mode, and android 13 debug and release mode.
But in release build for Android 12 and earlier surprise surprise th app is crashing without any error before even starts.
I'm completely unable to figure out what would be the problem, it's totally hard to debug or to know what's going on. Even with logcat.
I mean this is completely illogic in debug mode everything is working fine but not in release.and this only for versions earlier than android 13.
In android 13 everything is working in debug and release.
Can someone please orientate me which moments should i look for ?
Has anyone struggled with this kind of problem before that  ?

Comment: You may try connecting your real Android devices to the computer. Logcat in Android Studio can show error log also in release build. It is impossible to solve the issue without knowing the error. I guess you may encounter error like `couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so`.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have had similar issues before, and in some cases it was cased by the proguard removing classes that I needed.

Comment: Yeah, my trouble was caused by a package, react-native-rfid-nfc-scanner, it was beacsue devices don't support nfc, so it was not related to android version, also try to use logcat it's absulotely helpful fro debugging these type of issues, i had also an error with sentry so i just removed it. these were my issues that i've found